# Compilation error creating HttpHeaders using Collectors.toMap on the HttpServletRequest's headerNames Enumeration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to copy all existing headers from an `HttpServletRequest` to a Spring `HttpHeaders` object to use with `RestTemplate`. This can be done easily in a loop on enumeration, but I'm getting this error while using streams:

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
Enumeration<String> existingHeaders = request.getHeaderNames();

headers.putAll(
 Collections.list(existingHeaders)
.stream()
.collect(
Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),HttpServletRequest::getHeader))
);
```

I declared the variable `Enumeration<String>` for the stream to not consider elements as Object but I'm still getting this compilation error at `collect()`:

```
The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) 
in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments
(Function<Object,Object>, HttpServletRequest::getHeader)
```

Comment: You need an object to invoke `getHeader` on. So perhaps, instead of `HttpServletRequest::getHeader`, you mean `request::getHeader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not compile is that its `Collectors.toMap(...)` call is producing a `Map<String, String>`, but `headers.putAll(...)` requires a `Map<String, List<String>>`.  This can be fixed by changing the `Collectors.toMap(...)` call to produce a compatible map:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
Enumeration<String> existingHeaders = request.getHeaderNames();

headers.putAll(Collections.list(existingHeaders)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                name -> Collections.list(request.getHeaders(name)))));
```

Since the same HTTP header can have multiple values, [`HttpHeaders`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) implements `Map<String,List<String>>` rather than `Map<String,String>`.  Therefore, [`putAll(map)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) requires a map with `List<String>` values, not one with `String` values.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `HttpHeaders` from an `HttpServletRequest` you can use the [`ServletServerHttpRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpRequest.html) class in `spring-web`.  Since the `HttpHeaders` class is also in `spring-web`, you should already have this class available on your classpath.

```java
private static HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) {
  return new ServletServerHttpRequest(request).getHeaders();
}
```

This answer does not address why you're getting error you're receiving, though it does address the underlying problem you're attempting to solve: getting an `HttpHeaders` from an existing `HttpServletRequest`.